# Can one "feel" or "represent oneself in" spacetime?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime

My question is strongly related to the physics of relativity and any answer might resort to advanced concepts in physics, that's why I post here, although I feel it is at the edge of philosophy and might lack rigor.

Can one experience in daily life, in all honesty, evolving in spacetime, rather than moving in a 3D-space while being subject to the flow of time? How would you describe that experience?

In other words, does understanding the fundamentals of the theory of relativity makes it possible to "feel" time and space differently? Has its discovery paved the way towards a new feeling of time and space? If such evolution is ongoing, could it explain recent social or anthropologic evolutions?

Comment: I think you have to imagine you're a static wordline made up from your past, present, and future.

Comment: I was reading Rovelli's paper on Loop Quantum Gravity when I had the flash that in a different universe, if the size of the particles of LQG were larger or smaller, then the speed of light (and the rate of time) would be slower or faster.  This speculative idea helps me to envision spacetime in a new way. Imagine space filled with balloons. Near the energy of a planet these get larger.  Each balloon has a node and light travels between these nodes so slows down near a planet.  This would be the warping of spacetime of GR. While I can't feel GR, I can certainly see it, in this strange idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mostly no - see Niels Nielsen's answer. But *sort of*, insofar as we can have a personal experience of anything we don't directly interact with regularly.

We have a personal experience of living in spacetime in a way similar to how we have a personal experience of, e.g., living on a planet with an Arctic ice cap.

We could *experimentally verify* the presence of an ice cap by getting in a boat and going there. If we find a big floating barrier made of cold stuff with the chemical properties of frozen water after going far enough to the North, it constitutes strong evidence for the ice cap hypothesis. Likewise we could *experimentally verify* the claim that time works like a spatial dimension, for example, by doing a [relativity of simultaneity](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RelativityOfSimultaneity/) experiment with very precise clocks, which would constitute strong evidence for the spacetime hypothesis. This would inform our knowledge, but it wouldn't be relevant to our daily experience. As soon as the experiment is over, our senses tell us nothing different about the universe than before.

Alternatively, we could *map some facet of our regular daily experience* to things that specialists have demonstrated are consequences of the presence of an ice cap. For example, we are having this conversation in English. Historians know that English is the dominant language of intergroup communication indirectly because a bunch of people from England established a global empire a few hundred years ago, and one of their rebellious colonies did really well for itself. Climate scientists know that England had the characteristics necessary to launch an empire in large part because it was warmed by the Gulf Stream. Specialists who study ocean currents know that if there was no polar ice cap, the Gulf Stream would not pass northern Europe. Therefore, every time you think a thought in English, or hear someone speaking English, you can *infer* the truth of the ice cap hypothesis: *English implies British Empire implies Gulf Stream implies ice cap*.

Similaly, *microchip implies computer engineers implies physicists implies quantum mechanics implies spacetime*. All microchips are made according to specifications informed, way down at the theoretical level, by a set of axioms that includes a time dimension that can work like a spatial dimension. Therefore every time you interact with anything with a microchip, you can *infer* the predictive viability of the spacetime hypothesis.

---

Re: philosophy - the musings of philosophers and the activities of laypeople are informed by *beliefs*, not observations or facts. Much has been written in philosophy attempting to incorporate 20th century physics, but almost all of it has been written by people whose only understanding of said physics was nonmathematical and therefore prone to egregious error.

For example, the block universe model (in which a process's past, present, and future are all locations in a single 4-dimensional object) is often described (even by physicists) as past, present, and future all existing *simultaneously*. This is nonsense: different times are not at the same time by definition, just as different places are not at the same place. What has been done here is to promote the observer into a Supercosmos who somehow exists despite not being a part of all-that-exists, from which he can observe the timeless universe; posit without a shred of evidence the existence of a 5th dimension, Supertime, which is what a clock measures if you're in the Supercosmos, and which is *not* subject to relativistic effects, and redefine "simultaneous" to mean "at the same place in Supertime". That's not physics, it's a made-up fantasy that doesn't even make internal logical sense - but insofar as the idea of spacetime has influenced philosophy, that fantasy is probably the number one influence.

Answer (score 0):

Well, can you 'feel' it? I can't. And I don't think it's appropriate to post this question here because it's more related to biology and psychology than physics.

But I will still answer your question: We feel space by our four senses (excluding smelling) and we sense time by our 'biological clock', that is the clock that makes us tired and wanting to sleep after a busy day and that tells us when to eat and drink.

Understanding of physics have no effects on our biological sensation; we are born with what we have and it's impossible to add things on. However, it might have an impact on our cognition but that's on our psychological side

Answer (score 0):

The hypothetical spacetime sensations you describe would be necessarily impossible for us to detect, for the following reasons:

We know that for an outside observer, a speeding rocket ship going past us at relativistic velocities gets foreshortened along its direction of travel, turning it and everything inside it into a pancake shape the faster it goes. We would also observe that the hands on a clock attached to the spaceship would be moving more and more slowly the faster the spaceship went.

But to someone *inside* the speeding spaceship, all is normal, and when looking out a window at their surroundings rushing by they would see everything squashed & flattened, and everyone else's clocks slowed down.

This is another way of expressing the fundamental fact that the laws of the universe make no distinction at all between sitting at rest and zooming along at any (constant) speed we choose. The resting spectators are allowed to assert that they are standing still and it is the rocket that is moving, while the astronaut inside the rocket is equally allowed to assert that s/he is standing perfectly still and it is the spectators who are in motion.

This means there is *no possible physical measurement or physiological process* which would create a signal or produce any sensation connected with standing still versus moving at constant speed. This fact is woven into the fabric of the universe at the deepest possible level, and there is no escaping it.

Answer (score -1):

A process in relativity is represented as a static 4D worldline. So if you want to feel the process you are you have to imagine yourself as a bunch of static worldlines that are stretched in time. You don't know the future obviously. But you can imagine you bodily particles like beads on static iron threads extending from past to future in a 3D space.